# Conditionally include a column in a query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I essentially want the table width to be dynamic.

A single group set of my table columns would look like this.

```
Rank   Method   Number   BasedOn
---------------------------------
1      E        1        Null
2      W        2        Null
3      P        3        math
```

A SQL `CASE` to choose what a column contains is fairly simple

```sql
CASE
   WHEN Method = 'P' THEN BasedOn
   WHEN Method = 'E' THEN 'E'
END AS BasedOn
```

What I would like, is that if I filter the 'Rank' such that 'P' isn't in any row of column 'Method', then the BasedOn column is not selected.

Thus the pseudo code would look something like this

```sql
SELECT 
    Rank,
    Method,
    Number,
    CASE 
       WHEN Method CONTAINS 'P' THEN END AS BasedOn
       ELSE  
    END
FROM
    Table1
WHERE
    Rank IN (1, 2)
```

returning

```
Rank   Method   Number
----------------------
1      E        1
2      W        2
```

but if

```sql
SELECT 
    Rank,
    Method,
    Number,
    CASE 
       WHEN Method CONTAINS 'P' THEN 
    END AS BasedOn
    ELSE END
FROM 
    Table1
WHERE
    Rank IN (2, 3)
```

Then it should return

```
Rank   Method   Number   BasedOn
---------------------------------
2      W        2        Null
3      P        3        Math
```

Is this possible? How should I be aggregating the 'Method' column in my check?

Comment: A sql query must return a *fixed* set of columns, so what you are asking for cannot be achieved with pure sql. You would need dynamic SQL, which is another beast...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a monster, but with many thanks to Tanveer Badar, who keyed me into the `if exists` logic I present to you my results.

I will include one 'set' but in my final code I have the middle block replicated 11 times.

We start with the beginning declarations. I am using `LIKE` for my own reasons but your own purposes may vary.

```sql
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @UnionCode VARCHAR(10) = 'LXXX P'
SET @UnionCode = CONCAT('%',@UnionCode,'%')
DECLARE @CompanyCodeInput VARCHAR(2) = '31'
```

From there we move to the beginning of the SQL statement as a string.

```sql
--The beginning of the SQL statement.
SET @SQL = @SQL+'SELECT 
                [UnionGroupCode]
                ,[UnionName]
                '
```

Now we begin the first of N blocks.

```sql
--Employee Union Dues 1
IF exists (SELECT [Dues1RatePercentage] FROM Table_1
  WHERE [CompanyCode] = @CompanyCodeInput AND [UnionGroupCode] LIKE @UnionCode AND [Dues1RatePercentage] <> 0)
BEGIN
    IF exists (
    SELECT [Dues1Method] FROM Table_1
    WHERE [CompanyCode] = @CompanyCodeInput AND [UnionGroupCode] LIKE @UnionCode AND [Dues1Method] = 'P')
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL+',[Dues1RatePercentage] AS [Other 1]
            ,[Dues1Method] AS [Other 1 Method]
            ,[Dues1BasedOn] AS [Other 1 Based On]
            '
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = @SQL+',[Dues1RatePercentage] AS [Other 1]
            ,[Dues1Method] AS [Other 1 Method]
            '
    END
END
```

And then we close it off with this last block

```sql
--The end of the SQL statement
SET @SQL = @SQL+'FROM Table_1

  WHERE [CompanyCode] = '''+@CompanyCodeInput+''' AND [UnionGroupCode] LIKE '''+@UnionCode+'''

  ORDER BY [UnionGroupCode]'
PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Each center block of code checks 2 things.

```
'Should we even include the full set of columns?'
'If we should, should we include the BasedOn column?'
```

With these questions we have to be creative with the addition to the `@SQL`. I know what all the columns should be named, as such I can name them. However, it should be theoretically possible to also dynamically name the columns as well with an additional query bringing in a Description, adding another `DECLARE` to the first block for `@DynamicColumnName`and including in the first half of the `if exists`. A `SET @DynamicColumnName = [Description]` then changing the `AS [Other 1]` to be `AS ['+@DynamicColumnName+']` modifying as appropriate

Because of these two questions, we query the server at max (N*2)+1 times where N is the number of center blocks of code.

I want to stress that, while this is perfectly fine for me with my small database, it is terrible performance wise. My purposes are to run this once a month but also have it survive past my current employment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your query twice, and use `if()`. My t-sql is a bit rusty, but this should give you a good idea about how to start.

```
if exists (select * from table1 where method = 'P')
begin
    SELECT Rank, Method, Number, CASE WHEN Method = 'P' THEN METHOD END AS BasedOn END
    FROM Table1
end
else
begin
    SELECT Rank, Method, Number
    FROM Table1
end
```

Comment: My examples were for a single grouping of `Method Number BasedOn`. However my actual table contains 11 such groupings `Method3 Number3 BasedOn3` Is there anything you would change with that new information?

Something I would imagine would be the `WHERE` section would include multiple `AND`'s